# why I cannot pick an element on google sign in page

Tags: types, get, cypress, google-signin

[image: 1]

sorry I am new to cypress

I am trying to get() the value of Email or phone input box so I can use type()

weirdly, when I click the picker button, it is just not working, only on this google sign in page

```js
cy.get('mat-focus-indicator') is the value from the previous page
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

*Still a beginner but hopefully this would help*

I believe you are trying to sign in using google OAuth on another site which leads to the google page. Well unfortunately cypress can't visit two different domains in the same test the normal way. (The tests would lead to error because of change in domain)

Please refer to the following documentation that I hope would be of help to you.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/cross-origin-testing#Parts-of-a-URL